# Regarding application of job through agency.Is it necessary

Tags: job-search

I need some advice regarding  applying for jobs through agents Recently my friend  came across a recruiter who is working for an agency. The recruiter offered  my friend  a job which my friend  was willing to accept. My friend then told her that I could  be interested for the same job. She then told my friend to share the job details with  me. My friend  sent me  the job details and both of us applied.

We communicated through  WhatsApp. The agent  then call me and requested me to send my resume and other details. I submitted all the documents she requested  for. After that there was no update from her regarding the job. After a few days I messaged her and asked her how long must I wait for the reply. This is how she replied  me, 'Hello 1 week'. I was shocked to read the reply. Then I replied to her that I will wait for 1 week. A few days after a week, I messaged her kindly and asked her about my job application. Again she replied me 'Hello sorry unsuccessful'. Again, I got shocked  and started to think whether she did submit  my application to the client or not.

After that I always  received email about job recommendations. In that email I see the job which I have applied still needs employees. Not only that other agents recruiters also are advertising for the same job. In the same agency there are other recruiters who advertise for the same jobs.

**Question**: Is there anyway I can apply for the job directly to the company instead of going through an agency ?

Comment: Why are you **shocked** in these situations ? It happens a lot to many people when they are looking for jobs. Just calm down, and focus on applying for more jobs at many companies, **which is the key to getting a job**. Eventually, you will get a good job.

Comment: Please take a bit of time to format your post correctly - nobody wants to read a wall of text.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway I can apply for the job directly to the company instead of going through agency ?

You can go to the company website to search for jobs (visit their career page, etc...) Also, you can go to the company's LinkedIn or similar social media platforms to search for jobs.

You can also call the company's HR department to ask how you can apply for jobs.